# what kind of physical server can be enlisted to MAAS via PXE boot

Tags: maas, pxe

i found that some kind of physical servers(like DELL\HP\HUAWEI),maas can not control it's power.So is there some special requests to the server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware recommendation and off-topic here.

Comment: It's not off topic because the answer is sufficiently general that it is not a specific product recommendation

Answer (score 1):

Any server that has IPMI working can be controller by MAAS. Maas also has support for the following power drivers.

- American Power Conversion (APC) - PDU
- Cisco UCS Manager
- Digital Loggers, Inc. - PDU
- HP Moonshot - iLO Chassis Manager
- HP Moonshot - iLO4 (IPMI)
- IBM Hardware Management Console (HMC)
- Intel AMT
- Manual
- Microsoft OCS - Chassis Manager
- OpenStack Nova
- SeaMicro 15000
- Sentry Switch CDU - PDU
- VMWare
- Virsh (virtual systems)

---

See [offical documentation](http://maas.io/docs/en/manage-power) for more information.